# matplotlib - Spectrogram (v1.3.1)

Tags: python, audio, matplotlib

I'm interested in knowing just how matplotlib processes the spectrogram. I understand most parts, specifically in the FFT and others, but, to me the scaling does not seem correct. The default is to return the `PSD` of the signal, however, I cannot seem to replicate it whatsoever. For example, in matplotlib I get this result:

[image]

However, when trying to replicate this (in C++) I get this result:

In C++ and plotted with matplotlib I get this result:

[image]

I'm mainly interested in how they somehow "remove" the noise factor to show the bins which have the most power in them. The graph  I shove (above) in C++ I get similar results, yet, they are different.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
std::vector<std::vector<Complex::complex> > ComputeSTFT(std::vector<double> 
&vals, std::size_t NFFT, std::size_t overlap)
{
   std::vector<std::vector<double> > temp_vars = frame(vals, NFFT, overlap);
   std::vector<std::vector<Complex::complex> > STFT(temp_vars.size());
   std::vector<double> hanning = getHanningWindow(256);

   for(unsigned i=0; (i < temp_vars.size()); i++)
   {
      for(unsigned j=0; (j < temp_vars[i].size()); j++)
      {
         double calculation = temp_vars[i][j] * hanning[j];
         calculation = (calculation == -0) ? 0 : calculation;
         temp_vars[i][j] = calculation;
      }
   }

std::vector<std::vector<Complex::complex> > fft_vars(temp_vars.size());
for(unsigned i=0; (i < temp_vars.size()); i++)
{
   fft_vars.resize(temp_vars[i].size());

   FFT f(temp_vars[i].begin(), temp_vars[i].end(), temp_vars[i].size());
   std::vector<Complex::complex> temp_fft = f.transformed();
   fft_vars[i] = temp_fft;
}

for(unsigned i=0; (i < temp_vars.size()); i++)
{
   STFT[i].resize(temp_vars[i].size()/2+1);
   for(unsigned j=0; (j < temp_vars[i].size()/2 + 1); j++)
   {   
       STFT[i][j].re = fft_vars[i][j].re;
       STFT[i][j].im = fft_vars[i][j].im;
    }
}

return STFT;
}



std::vector<double> CalculatePSD(std::vector<Complex::complex> &vals)
{
  std::vector<double> result(vals.size());

  for(unsigned i=0; (i < vals.size()); i++)
  {
    double mag = vals[i].re * vals[i].re + vals[i].im * vals[i].im;
    result[i] = mag;
  }
  std::vector<double> hanning = getHanningWindow(128);
  double sum = 0.0;

  for(unsigned i=0; (i < vals.size()); i++)
  {
     sum += abs(hanning[i]);
  }



for(unsigned i=0; (i < vals.size()); i++)
{
    result[i] = result[i] * 2/(12000)*sum;
    //result[i] /= sum;
    //result[i] *= 1;
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: Are there any `noverlap` and `window` process in your C++ code?

Comment: @HYRY - yes 128 overlap same as what's in matplotlib mhm think this could be the case? Also multiplying by hamming window (256)

Comment: Then please theck the python code of `pylab.specgram`: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/mlab.py#L644

Comment: This also just got a major overhaul.

Comment: @HYRY that is what I have been doing...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211726/trying-to-compute-power-spectrum-density please see here

Comment: @tcaswell - how do you mean,sorry?

Comment: The spectrogram code got a bunch of work done to (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2522).  This will be in 1.4 (that will be cut off of master 'soon').

Comment: @tcaswell - so my result (2nd plot) could actually be correct, then?

Comment: I have no idea if your code or results are correct as I can't see your data or your code.  And if you are using 1.3.1 then you do not have the new code in your installation yet.

Comment: Please see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211726/trying-to-compute-power-spectrum-density where I show the code.. Is there any other way I can check my results? Mhm thanks though